# Mysqld won't start

Tags: centos, restart, mysql

i'm trying to start mysqld but it won't start..

```
[root@jack ~]#service mysqld restart
Interruzione di mysqld:                                    [  OK  ]
```

and it stops here.. it won't start.. what could be the problem? can someone help me? thanks!

Comment: What are the outputs of 'mysqld stop' and 'mysqld start'? Also, what does the mysql log file show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the partition full!!! :) Just remove some file and start mysqld to let it work again! ;)